# How to get a different result for each click event in jQuery using lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, for-loop, iteration

I am ***extremely*** new to javascript, and I just can not wrap my head around for loops and variable lists. It seems like every tutorial half way explains it and then rambles/mubles on the rest of the way and doesn't really make it clear.

So, I decided to make a `div` a different color for each time it's clicked, which iterates through four colors.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #ea5243;
}
```

**JavaScript (using jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var colors = ["#b8d30b", "#0099cc", "#e63f35", "#fbd108"];
     for(var i in colors) {
         $(".myDiv").on("click", function() {
             $(this).css("background", colors);
         });
     }
});
```

Obviously this will not work, but as you can see, I want to rotate through each color code per click.

I have tried googling my problem, but found it hard to phase, therefore no avail. And as I said, I am very new to javascript.

Comment: You'll need to add a counter and increment with each click. I'll take a stab at it if I have time.

Comment: Okay! Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Here's your code in a fiddle as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/ttgTj/

Comment: We're gonna wanna to include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ttgTj/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ttgTj/4

```
var colors = ["#b8d30b", "#0099cc", "#e63f35", "#fbd108"];
var i = 0;
$(".myDiv").on("click", function () {
    $(this).css("background", colors[i]);
    i = (++i >= colors.length)? 0: i;
});
```

Comment: E.P.'s answer covers it nicely. I won't bother going further unless you need it.

Comment: And Derek took care of it for me anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I like this one, it's short, nice and works. However, I went with E.P.'s answer because of it's logic which helps me understand a little better. Thanks again! +1

Comment: @randmath - Just a note here, EP's method *will* change the order of the Array. So if you don't want to mess up its order, go with this one instead.

Comment: I actually decided to use this as it doesn't mess with the order. Thanks!

Comment: @isherwood instead of using the last line, you can use `colors[i % colors.length]`

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. I'm not sure exactly what it's doing. Please link to a reference if you have one.

Comment: @isherwood - [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) gives you the remainder, eg: `7 % 3 -> 1` Actually using `%` here is very smart :D

Answer (score 4):

You can keep shifting and pushing values from the colors array.  This is a bit more advanced then just for loops, but it's good to learn about it too.  You don't even have to worry about the length of colors.

```
var colors = ["#b8d30b", "#0099cc", "#e63f35", "#fbd108"];
$(".myDiv").on('click', function () {
    //removes the zeroth element from the array
    var color = colors.shift();

    $(this).css('background-color', color);

    //puts the "pushed" element at the end of the array
    colors.push(color);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/F79jd/

Comment: E.P., are you ever not on SO? How about laying off the easy ones for us newbies? ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This works! But I decided to go with isherwoods (it doesn't mess up the order). Plus, @E.P. has 38.5k rep. That's......... A lot.

Comment: @isherwood once I have a gold JavaScript badge I'll move on to other tags

Comment: I'd have never guessed that you were here for the glory. :P